# Why is Spotify botching my Node Component builds?

Tags: javascript, node.js, spotify, chromium-embedded

Can anyone think of any reason why my [Component](https://github.com/component/component) custom builds might be failing every time (seemingly without fail) my [Spotify](https://www.spotify.com) application is open?

I have noticed varying errors, but this is the most common.

```
error : Command failed: 
Error: UNKNOWN, unknown error 'path/to/component.json'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:427:18)
    at fs.readFileSync (fs.js:284:15)
    at Builder.json (path/to/node_modules/component-builder/lib/builder.js:428:13)
    at new Builder (path/to/node_modules/component-builder/lib/builder.js:62:22)
    at path/to/node_modules/component-builder/lib/builder.js:649:25
    at next (path/to/node_modules/component-builder/lib/builder.js:291:14)
    at Builder.lookup (path/to/node_modules/component-builder/lib/builder.js:307:3)
    at path/to/node_modules/component-builder/lib/builder.js:646:14
    at path/to/node_modules/batch/lib/batch.js:65:5
    at Array.forEach (native)
```

Obviously a quick-fix is closing Spotify, but I'm intrigued as to why this may be happening? Could Spotify be using a hefty JavaScript VM which is fighting for read/write streams? Need some lower-level scholar with some *out-there* ideas...

I'm on Retina MBP with OSX Mountain Lion.

Comment: My guesses are either port collisions or temp file collisions, or Spotify maxed out open file descriptors. I'd look into seeing what files and sockets each process has open.

Comment: To clarify, do you mean the Spotify desktop or web client?

Comment: @DavidEhrmann Thanks for your input. Yes, the desktop application.

Comment: If it's the desktop client, it's almost certainly port numbers, file descriptors, files, CPU, or IO. Can you list the ports open by process, see what Spotify is using? Then, either manually bind to them (`nc -l <port num>`) or use something like `ktrace` to log system calls and see which files and ports are getting opened.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann Ok, thanks for your help. I'll play the long game with this one: reporting back in a couple of months when I have the time and inclination to investigate. :-)